# How do I create a line graph with 2 lines where x is year and y is proportion of total rather than raw count?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I am working with data on 2 prescription drugs. There is a generic drug and a name brand drug. They are like the same drug except one is way cheaper. I have data that is broken down by several variables including quarter, year, number of prescriptions in that time period, and drug name (as a character variable). My current code I have is below.

```
alldrugs %>%
  filter(product_name == "DIMETHYL F" | product_name == "TECFIDERA ") %>%
  mutate(yr_q = yq(paste(year, quarter)), number_of_prescriptions = as.numeric(x = number_of_prescriptions)) %>%
  group_by(product_name, yr_q)%>%
  summarize(Prescription.count = sum(number_of_prescriptions)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = yr_q, y = Prescription.count)) + geom_line(aes(colour=product_name), size = 1.4) +
  xlab("2020-2022") + 
  ylab("Number of Prescriptions") + 
  labs(colour = "Generic vs Name Brand") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: What graph looks like]

The issue is, I need the y-axis to not be number of prescriptions, but instead be proportion of total in that time period. I.e. for the tecfidera line it should represent (# tecfidera prescriptions in that time period/ total of tecfidera + dimethyl f).

Bonus points if you can help me do a similar thing but create a table that breaks down the proportion (ie tecfidera/total tec+ dimethyl) but by state and year. (I have state variable)

I was thinking maybe some type of
`mutate(dummy.product_name = case_when(product_name == 'tecfidera' ~ 1, product_name == "dimethyl f" ~ 0))`   but I don't think that solves the issue.

Or maybe line graph is the wrong choice, I was toying with:

```
 ggplot(alldrugs, aes( x = year, y = number_of_prescriptions, fill = product_name)) +
 +    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .5, position = "dodge") +
+     facet_grid(~year)
```

but that comes out really ugly although I think it has potential maybe.

Thank you so much for any help!!

Here is a dput I believe of a subset of 25 observations
`structure(list(state = c("AK", "CA", "OR", "MN", "NY", "UT",  "AK", "AK", "CA", "NJ", "AK", "NY", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK",  "AK", "SC", "NC", "NM", "AK", "AK", "AK", "CA"), year = c("2020",  "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2022",  "2022", "2022", "2022", "2021", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2020",  "2020", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2022" ), quarter = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2",  "3", "4", "1", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1",  "2", "3"), product_name = c("GILENYA   ", "GILENYA   ", "GILENYA   ",  "GILENYA   ", "GILENYA   ", "GILENYA   ", "GILENYA   ", "GILENYA   ",  "GILENYA   ", "GILENYA   ", "GILENYA   ", "GILENYA   ", "DIMETHYL F",  "DIMETHYL F", "DIMETHYL F", "DIMETHYL F", "DIMETHYL F", "DIMETHYL F",  "DIMETHYL F", "DIMETHYL F", "DIMETHYL F", "DIMETHYL F", "DIMETHYL F",  "DIMETHYL F", "DIMETHYL F"), number_of_prescriptions = c("10",  "1", "4", "6", "1", "7", "2", "9", "3", "7", "6", "4", "3", "2",  "4", "9", "8", "2", "1", "10", "6", "9", "10", "3", "8")), row.names = c(NA,  25L), class = "data.frame")`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vNfqdm5gPXL21PXjkPe512ZFcBzU-qUI7baQACRO7ag/edit#gid=0

Link to spreadsheet of the data as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(alldrugs)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Hi @neilfws thanks for the quick reply. It is a large dataset with around 5500 observations. Is there a way I could restrict it to only pump out like 20 observations to make it shorter?

Comment: Try `dput(head(alldrugs, 20))`. Or you can always link to an online file (using _e.g._ a Google spreadsheet), for larger datasets.

Comment: @neilfws Ok I have just posted a dput of the data as well as a link to a spreadsheet! The full dataset has a lot more variables but I only selected the relevant variables in the dput.

Comment: Is `yq` from the `dint` package or where?

Comment: @JonSpring That is from lubridate. The dataset started off with year and quarter as separate variables so I used that to combine into a single Year_Quarter variable.  Packages im using are: ggplot2 , tidyverse, dplyr , lubridate , zoo. Always open to using more if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alldrugs %>%
  count(product_name, yr_q = lubridate::yq(paste(year, quarter)),
        wt = as.numeric(number_of_prescriptions)) %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n), .by = yr_q) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = yr_q, y = share)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=product_name), size = 1.4) +
  xlab("2020-2022") + 
  ylab("Number of Prescriptions") + 
  labs(colour = "Generic vs Name Brand") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: You sir are a genius, thank you, this looks like exactly what I need, and thank you to neilfws for helping me make the data reproducible. Edit: Oh you changed the code a little bit after I replied, I am assuming this is a bit cleaner.